# Pronouncing the symbols $\oplus,\otimes,\rtimes,\cup$, and $\cap$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, pronunciation

I'm trying to figure out how to pronounce the symbols $\oplus,\otimes,\rtimes,\cup$, and $\cap$ when they're being used as binary operators in the contexts of direct sums, tensor products, semidirect products, unions, and intersections, respectively.

I was noticing that we can read aloud $a + b$ either as *the sum of $a$ and $b$* **or** as *$a$ plus $b$*, and likewise we can read aloud $a\times b$ as *the product of $a$ and $b$* **or** as *$a$ times $b$*.

However, I've only read that I should pronounce:

- $A\oplus B$ as *the direct sum of $A$ and $B$*,
- $A\otimes B$ as *the tensor product of $A$ and $B$*,
- $A\rtimes B$ as *the semidirect product of $A$ and $B$*
- $A\cup B$ as *the union of $A$ and $B$*, and
- $A\cap B$ as *the intersection of $A$ and $B$*.

I'm wondering: are there similar alternatives for how to say the above expressions in the form "$A$ [name of binary operator] $B$"? Obviously I can pronounce them using their standard LaTeX symbol names, but I was wondering if there were other alternatives? As an example, one of my professors pronounces $A\otimes B$ as *$A$ tensor $B$* (he doesn't say *$A$ otimes $B$*), but I wasn't sure if that was common or just his own habit.

Comment: I sometimes say "A oplus B", just literally reading aloud the latex markup. Also for "cup", "cap", but not "otimes", which I always call "tensor". And I have never called the semidirect product "rtimes" which is the latex, I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"$A$ cup $B$" and "$A$ cap $B$" are standard for union and intersection. "$A$ tensor $B$" is common for the tensor product. I have never heard anyone use a short name for direct sum or semidirect product or use "oplus" or "otimes" other than when referring to the $\LaTeX$ macros.

Comment: I have never heard anyone say "$A$ cup $B$" or "$A$ cap $B$" (unless referring to cup and cap products).  Very common in my experience is "$A$ union $B$" and "$A$ intersect $B$".